# How can I pass children to a component in a slim template using react_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, slim-lang, react-rails

I'm using [react_rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) to render react components inside of a slim template in a Ruby on Rails application. Is there a way to pass children to a React component, where the children are rendered server-side in slim?

Here is what I would ideally like to have:

```
<MyComponent>
  <p>my custom content</p>
</MyComponent>
```

Where the content comes from the template itself, something like this:

```
= react_component 'MyComponent' do 
  p my custom content
```

Is this possible? If so what's the best way to pass children to a react_component?

Answer (score -1):

On page load, the react_ujs driver will scan the page and mount components using data-react-class and data-react-props.

The view helper's signature is:
`react_component(component_class_name, props={}, html_options={})`